# VBA Excel : A find and replace for charts titles

Tags: excel, vba, replace, charts, find

I am making a macro that do a simple replacement in all chart titles. It works very well but suppress all format : italic, bold, ...
Here is the code :

```
    Function trouverItalique(ByRef g As ChartObject)
            Dim phrase As String
        For i = 0 To Len(g.Chart.ChartTitle.Text)
            If InStr(g.Chart.ChartTitle.Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle, "Italic") > 0 Then
                phrase = phrase & g.Chart.ChartTitle.Characters(i, 1).Text
            End If
        Next
        trouverItalique = phrase
End Function
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim char As ChartObject
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each char In s.ChartObjects
        If char.Chart.HasTitle Then
            Dim phrase As String
            'phrase = trouverItalique(char)
            'char.Chart.ChartArea.AutoScaleFont = False
            char.Chart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = replace(char.Chart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text, TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
            Dim index As Integer
            'index = InStr(char.Chart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text, phrase)
            'char.Chart.ChartTitle.Characters(index, Len(phrase)).Font.Italic = True
        End If
    Next
    Next
End Sub
```

It works only for some cases and only for to keep the italic, I would like to keep bold and other formats. Do you have an idea to make my code works for any case ? Did I miss a cool mecanism to do the same thing without all of my peregrination ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub tester()

    ReplaceTitle ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart, "ghj", "fffffff"

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceTitle(cht As Chart, ReplaceWhat As String, ReplaceWith As String)
    Dim sTitle As String, pos
    If cht.HasTitle Then
        pos = InStr(cht.ChartTitle.Characters.Text, ReplaceWhat)
        If pos > 0 Then
            cht.ChartTitle.Characters(pos, Len(ReplaceWhat)).Text = ReplaceWith
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I didn't even think about a method like that, it works.